# Python когда следует использовать async, а когда await?

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio, async-await

Когда следует использовать async, а когда await?

Answer (score 17):

`async`, например, задает асинхронную функцию

```py
async def f():
    return 5
```

Или указывает, что `for` асинхронный, т.е. получает значения из асинхронного генератора

```py
async def generator():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

async def main():
    async for x in generator():
        print(x)
```

Или позволяет работать с асинхронной версией контекстного менеджера

```py
async with await asyncio.start_server(callback, '127.0.0.1', 8080) as server:
    await server.serve_forever()
```

А `await` ожидает завершения `awaitable` объекта и возвращает результат.

```py
async main():
    print(await f())
```

Их сложно перепутать: `async` - это часть утверждения (statement), `await` - унарный оператор, часть выражения (expression)

`await`, `async for` и `async with` должны использоваться только внутри асинхронной функции.

Answer (score 15):

Попытаюсь дополнить ответ @extrn.

`async/await` - это оптимизация, т.е. использовать их категорически не надо там, где все и так работает хорошо. Ведь это усложняет логику исполнения программы и тянет за собой много всего. Потому что если решились использовать асинхронную функциональность - будьте добры использовать ТОЛЬКО библиотеки, которые это поддерживают.

Исполнение асинхронного кода подобно исполнению многопоточного кода на одноядерном процессоре. Так же существуют несколько задач, которые могут быть исполнены одновременно и есть контекст исполнения каждой задачи. Однако при многопоточности процессор сам по таймеру решает, когда переключать контекст и заниматься исполнением другой задачи.

Асинхронный подход предполагает, что в само приложение задает специальные места, где такое переключение возможно. В Python в `asyncio` этими местами становятся вызовы с `await`.

Если решились оптимизировать, то в первую очередь стоит вспомнить что такое и чем различаются CPU-bound и IO-bound операции. Первые постоянно задействуют ресурсы процессора, все время что-то считают и вычисляют. Вторые большую часть времени ожидают операций ввода/вывода от файловой системы, сети или еще невесть чего.

Из-за GIL в Python (CPython) CPU-bound операции невозможно оптимизировать с использованием потоков, только вынесением в отдельный процесс. Совершенно то же самое ограничение накладывается на использование асинхронного подхода, потому что асинхронный код преимущественно одноядерный и если один исполнитель будет переключаться с одного процесса на другой, где его присутствие одинаково важно - никакого толку не будет (будет гораздо хуже).

Другое дело IO-bound задачи. Яркими примерами могут служить - чтение файлов, запрос в базу данных, даже `time.sleep` (который часто используется для имитации сложных IO-bound операций и есть специальный `asyncio.sleep`).

Например:

```
def create_report(cursor, *args, **kwargs):
    # выполнить какую-то подготовительную работу
    data = cursor.execute(sql_query)
    # обработать полученные данные и сформировать некий отчет
```

Здесь функция `execute` не сильно нагрузит процессор, больше будет ждать ответа от базы данных. Поэтому процессору позволительно заняться в этот момент чем-нибудь другим. Но этот код синхронный, приходится ждать. Если нам надо построить очень много таких отчетов, то мы можем решиться оптимизировать это с использованием `asyncio`. Давайте попробуем.

Сначала нам придется выбросить старый клиент для похода в базу данных и использовать специальный асинхронный, который будет осуществлять неблокирующий вызов.

```
async def create_report(cursor, *args, **kwargs):
    # cursor - это уже не тот cursor, что из предыдущего примера
    # выполнить какую-то подготовительную работу
    data = await cursor.execute(sql_query)
    # обработать полученные данные и сформировать некий отчет
```

Любая функция, которая использует `await` обязана объявляться как `async` - тут нет выбора. А `await` объявляет точку в программе, в которой мы можем переключиться на другую полезную работу, если такая есть, потому что ресурсы процессора здесь не нужны. Таким образом мы сможем успеть больше.

Оставляю за скобками инициализацию event-loop и прочие прелести запуска асинхронных программ.

Очень важно - сказал "А" (`async`), говори "B" (`await`), друг без друга они не существуют.

Крайне внятной я нашел следующую информацию:

[Async IO in Python: A Complete Walkthrough](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/)

[Getting Started With Async Features in Python](https://realpython.com/python-async-features/)

Не знаю, есть ли в интернете перевод этого добра, но если нужен, я мог бы подготовить.

Напоследок, интересное утверждение: "используйте асинхронность, когда можете, а потоки - когда должны".

Comment: Небольшое уточнение: переключением нативных потоков и процессов занимается планировщик операционки, а не процессор. Или, если это зелёные потоки, то - рантайм/виртуальная машина.