# Python - ускорить обработку событий

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, оптимизация, процесс

Пишу чат-бота, который принимает событие -> обрабатывает его -> отправляет ответ. Есть такие события, которые обрабатываются достаточно долго. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: если таких "сложных" событий слишком много подряд, то бот на время их обработки "зависает".

Использовал threading - но при использовании хотя бы 2 потоков запросы к базе данных sqlite3 и сложные вычислительные операции выполняются долго. 
Хотел использовать асинхронность - но это всё та же работа в одном потоке, при обработке сложного события она не ускорит бота.

Смотрел в сторону multiprocessing - но слишком много трудностей вижу в  использовании процессов.

Что можно сделать в такой ситуации? Или вопрос можно решить, только используя процессы?

Comment: асинхронность плюс пул процессов как экзекутор

Comment: Я тут отвечал по поводу асинхронности и вскользь затронул потоки. Почитайте, пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/988985/python-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-async-%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-await/1070892#1070892, может оказаться полезным для понимания масштаба задачи.

Comment: А вообще, стоит показать, что вы уже попробовали. Например, как измеряли что значит "долго" и насколько быстрее бы хотелось? А главное - какая конкретная трудность встала на пути с использованием multiprocessing?