# прерывание асинхронной функции Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Всем привет.
Имеется чередование в выполнении кода задач, реализованное, например так:

```
def func1():
    n = 0
    while True:
       print(n)
       n += 1
       yield

def func2():
    n = 10000
    while True:
       print(n)
       n += 1
       yield

def main():
    task1 = func1()
    task2 = func2()
    tasks = [task1, task2]
    while True:
        for task in tasks:
            next(task)

main()
```

Как реализовать данную задачу, используя синтаксис async/await без помощи asyncio.sleep.

Comment: И чего этим хочется добиться? Если это CPU-bound задачи (а в этом сферическом примере все именно так) - тогда переписывать в асинхроном виде не имеет никакого смысла, наоборот - это нанесет непоправимый вред кодовой базе и производительности приложения. Если это IO-bound задачи, то проблемы никакой нет - все операции ввода/вывода вызываются с await и все хорошо чередуется.

Comment: Этот абстрактный пример. Интересует сам принцип. Ведь зачем для прерывания функции и переходу к циклу событий во всех примерах используют asyncio.sleep(0). Зачем лишние манипуляции со временем, когда нужно всего лишь провернуть очередь. Кстати, это можно использовать в CPU-bound тяжелых задачах, где каждый фрагмент, к примеру, считается по 2-3 секунды, потом переключение. Или мне нужно 10 минут ждать выполнения одной задачи, чтобы перейти к другой?

Comment: В случае CPU-bound, для повышения эффективности надо использовать модуль multiprocessing, раз уж это независимые задачи.

Comment: Я не знаю, где пишут sleep на ноль секунд - это какой-то высосанный из пальца не очень популярный пример. Асинхронный код исполняется в одном потоке - одним исполнителем. Разумно ли ему переключаться между задачами, которые требуют 100% участия? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/988985/python-когда-следует-использовать-async-а-когда-await/1070892#1070892 тут могут быть интересные подробности.