# Асинхронный модуль работы с базой данных postgresql на python

Tags: python, postgresql, бот, async-await, aiogram

Буду благодарен за помощь. Хочу данный код сделать в асинхронном стиле c использованием asyncpg?
В данном примере https://github.com/alexey-goloburdin/telegram-finance-bot модуль работы с базой данных представлен в синхронном стиле, однако используется асинхронная библиотека aiogram. Имеет ли смысл переписывать мне мой модуль? Будет ли давать это прирост производительности?
Сейчас пока даже не понимаю с чего подступится. В частности нет понимания как должен выглядеть декоратор command, методы: _get_connection, select_table, init_db, insert_db_exhibition_info.

````
import psycopg2

def command(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cursor = self._get_connection().cursor()            # открываем курсор
        res = func(self, *args, cursor=cursor, **kwargs)    # выполняем функцию
        self._get_connection().commit()                     # коммит, если он нужен
        cursor.close()                                      # закрываем курсор
        return res
    return wrapper


class DbHelper():
    def __init__(self, db_name: str, user: str, password: str):
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self._connection = None    # connection object


    def _get_connection(self):
        if not self._connection:   # ленивая инициализация соединения
            self._connection = psycopg2.connect(database=self.db_name, user=self.user, password=self.password)
        return self._connection

    def __del__(self):
        if self._connection:        # закрытие соединения при удалении объекта как пример безопасной работы
            self._connection.close()

    @command                        # создаем новые таблицы в БД
    def init_db(self, cursor, force: bool = False):
        if force:
            cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dogs_info')

            self._connection.commit()

        # таблица с данными о собаках
        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dogs_info (
                           id              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                           dogs_name       VARCHAR(30),
                           dogs_age        INTEGER NOT NULL,
                           prize_place     INTEGER''')

    @command
    def insert_db_exhibition_info(self, cursor, dogs_name, dogs_age, prize_place):            # вносим в таблицу инофрмацию о собаках
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dogs_info (dogs_name, dogs_age, prize_place) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',
                       (dogs_name, dogs_age, prize_place))

    @command
    def select_table(self, cursor):
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM dogs_info')
        return cursor.fetchall()

    @command
    def delete_table_dogs_info(self, cursor):
        cursor.execute('DELETE FROM dogs_info')```
````

Answer (score 1):

> Имеет ли смысл переписывать мне мой модуль?

Это необходимо сделать. Здесь я многим повторю [свой ответ здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/988985/python-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-async-%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-await/1070892#1070892). При использовании asyncio любые вызовы синхронных IO-bound операций в асинхронных (корутинах/сопрограммах) ни к чему хорошему не приводят и сводят на нет целесообразность использования asyncio. Главная причина: все у нас выполняется в одном потоке.

Допустим, есть такой псевдокод.

```
@message_handler
async def wellcome():
    get_data_from_db()
    await reply_to_user()
```

На каждое входящее сообщение, будет вызываться этот обработчик. А так как он объявлен с использованием `async` - это корутина.

Здесь очевидно, что `get_data_from_db` реализована синхронно, потому что вызывается без `await`. Ну и это точно IO-bound операция, так как мы будем ждать завершения операций ввода/вывода после обращения к базе данных. Допустим, что пришло 10 сообщений - значит у нас создается и запускается 10 корутин.

Как они будут выполняться?

Под капотом у нас есть event-loop, который следит за выполнением корутин. Он выстраивает их в очередь и запускает. Работает всегда только одна, остальные в очереди.

Сначала первая сделает запрос в базу и... Будет ждать. Остальные 9 рады бы поделать какую-нибудь полезную работу, например, приступить к подготовке запроса и его отправке. Однако у нас нет параллельных потоков, корутины исполняются последовательно, но event-loop реализует механизм переключения между разными корутинами, чтобы выполнять все это совместно.

Если корутина заблокировала поток управления, то event-loop никогда не узнает, что вот сейчас мы не готовы сразу продолжить работу и можно пока другую корутину из очереди позвать поработать. Корутина должна сама сказать. Как?

С помощью `await`, однако произвольную фунцию нельзя вызвать с `await`. Это должна быть корутина. Следовательно `get_data_from_db` надо объявить с использованием `async` и в ней использовать только неблокирующие операции, т.е. использовать специальные библиотеки с поддержкой асинхронности, коей является asyncpg.

> Будет ли давать это прирост производительности?

Будет, за счет конкурентности. Процессор будет выполнять больше полезной работы, а не ждать ввода вывода. Это обеспечит гораздо большую пропускную способность, ибо клиенты ждущие данных из базы не будут блокировать тех, для которых уже все готово.

PS: Код из вашего примера как раз вызывает [синхронные IO-bound перации](https://github.com/alexey-goloburdin/telegram-finance-bot/blob/master/db.py) в [корутинах-обработчиках](https://github.com/alexey-goloburdin/telegram-finance-bot/blob/master/server.py). Использовать встроенный sqlite3 совершенно не уместно. Тут нужно было что-то вроде [aiosqlite](https://github.com/omnilib/aiosqlite).

PPS: До изобретения asyncio использовали [другую библиотеку (pyTelegramBotAPI)](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI), которая не задействует асинхронность, а обработка каждого входящего сообщения отдается на исполнение пулом потоков. При использовании IO-bound операций мы не испытываем проблем с GIL.

PPPS: Асинхронная программа должна быть асинхронная везде. Любой синхронный вызов надо уносить в отдельный поток и запускать с использованием метода [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), чтобы не сломать основную идею переключения между корутинами.

---

По поводу того, как должен выглядеть декоратор.

Вспомним, что запись:

```
@decorate
def func():
    pass
```

Эквивалентна:

```
def func():
    pass

func = decorate(func)
```

Чтобы обернуть корутину, надо из декоратора вернуть корутину

```
def decorate(func):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Получаем соединение
        res = await func(*args, **kwargs)
        # Коммитим
        return res
    return wrapper
```

И тогда можно будет нормально задекорировать любую асинхронную функцию.

А методам `DBHelper` достаточно добавить `async` к `def` и дальше руководствоваться API библиотеки asyncpg. Хорошо, что оно почти не отличается от psycopg, однако отличия есть и это может породить довольно долгую кропотливую отладку.

Там, например, `cursor` по-другому используется. К объекту подключения к базе можно сразу `execute` делать, для транзакций там надо использовать контекстный менеджер `async with` и все такое. [Тут лучше самому во всем разобраться и накопить конкретных вопросов.](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/)

Но ни в коем случае нельзя `__init__` и `__del__` объявлять `async`. Это служебные методы, которые вызываются не нами, они по своему строению синхронные. `__init__` можно оставить как есть, а закрытие соединения делать явно, отдельным методом, по крайней мере, пока, глядя на получающийся код, не придут в голову варианты получше.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Скажите пожалуйста а как может выглядеть модуль из вопроса с использованием asyncpg? Я просто не знаю точно где делать ли async для __init___, __del__, _get_connection(self)? И как сделать декоратор command в async? Хочется посмотерть как будет выглядеть класс модуля работы с БД с использованием asyncpg. Я в интернете так примера и не нашел

Comment: @Alex, ответ примером асинхронного декоратора `command` дополнил. По поводу переписывания `DBHelper` попробовал описать направление мысли в надежде, что поможет:)

Comment: Добавочку в коммент помещу по поводу вопроса `"Имеет ли смысл переписывать мне мой модуль?"`, я ответил, что обязательно надо. Не совсем обязательно прям переписывать. Точно нельзя оставлять как есть - это факт, а если оставить, то это грубая ошибка проектирования, считаю. Может сгодиться подход, что там я говорил про run_in_executor. Цель - обучение? Тогда можно себе позволить:) А если нужно перевести на асинхронный подход большую работающую систему - это уже совсем другое.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Попробую переписать!