# Отличия обычного Telegram бота от асинхронного?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, aiogram

Недавно начал изучать тему создания Telegram ботов на Python. Начал писать на pytelegrambotapi, но на многих сайтах все рекомендуют за место этой библиотеки учить aiogram. Основным его плюсом считают асинхронность. Может ли кто-нибудь разъяснить неопытному программисту, в чем различия асинхронного бота от обычного, и где это пригодится? И стоит ли в таком случае учить aiogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> в чем различия асинхронного бота от обычного

Пользователи шлют через специальные клиенты telegram боту сообщение. Бот получает сообщение и приступает к выполнению логики, которая как-то зависит от сообщения. На этом этапе `pytelegrambotapi` и `aiogram` ничем не отличаются.

Далее. Эта логика может потребовать получить какую-нибудь информацию из БД, что можно сделать?

1. Послать запрос и смиренно ждать, когда придет ответ. Тем временем очередь входящих сообщений может копиться.
2. Послать запрос и обрабатывать другое сообщение, но вернуться к этому позже, когда результат будет готов.

В первом случае сообщение обрабатывается синхронно, во втором асинхронно. В этом проявляются ключевые различия.

Быть может полезно будет почитать один мой другой ответ про async/await: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1070892/271103